# What is the correct AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin response header for AMP Email Playground?

Tags: cors, amp-html, amp-email

The documentation for [amp-email "security requirements"](https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/security-requirements#cors_headers) states:

> All responses must echo the origin and __amp_source_origin values from above if they are valid:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://amp.gmail.dev
AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: amp@gmail.dev
Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin
```

> If the response doesn't contain these values, the CORS request fail, resulting in a browser console warning message.

I am testing the use of amp-list in the playground, and my response contains these headers. However, the data does not appear, and in the console I get the following error: `Request xhr failed: The amp-access-control-allow-source-origin must be equal to the amp source origin sent in the request.​​​` The `amp_source_origin` provided in the request is `amp@gmail.dev` as expected.

Here is a copy of the relevant response headers I return:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://amp.gmail.dev
Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin
Amp-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: amp@gmail.dev
```

Is there some additional header I need to provide?

Comment: Replace `Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin` with `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` in your returned headers - seems there is an error in Gmail documentation right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct headers for CORS in the Gmail AMP Playground are the following:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://amp.gmail.dev
AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: amp@gmail.dev
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin
```

Gmail's documentation originally had an error where `Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin` was incorrectly used instead of `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`, but this is now fixed.